# apache_beam spark runner with python can't be implemented on remote spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

i am following the python guide [beam spark runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/),and the beam_pipeline can submit job to a local jobserver which is launched by `./gradlew :runners:spark:job-server:runShadow` with a local spark,
and the addition parameter`-PsparkMasterUrl=spark://localhost:7077` to a pre-deployed spark.

But i have a spark cluster on yarn, i set the launch  command as `./gradlew :runners:spark:job-server:runShadow -PsparkMasterUrl=yarn(also tried yarn-client)`, but only get `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'yarn'`

and the source code of the spark runner(beam\sdks\python\apache_beam\runners\portability\spark_runnner.py) shows that:

```
parser.add_argument('--spark_master_url',
                        default='local[4]',
                        help='Spark master URL (spark://HOST:PORT). '
                             'Use "local" (single-threaded) or "local[*]" '
                             '(multi-threaded) to start a local cluster for '
                             'the execution.')
```

it doesn't mention 'yarn', and the Provided SparkContext and StreamingListeners are not supported on the Spark portable runner. So does that meaning apache_beam spark runner with python can't be implemented on remote spark cluster(yarn mostly) and can only be test locally? or maybe i can set the job_endpoint as the remote job server url of my spark cluster.

and the every `./gradlew` command blocked at 98%,but the jab server started with info like that:

```
19/11/28 13:47:48 INFO org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.jobsubmission.JobServerDriver: JobService started on localhost:8099
<============-> 98% EXECUTING [16s]
> IDLE
> :runners:spark:job-server:runShadow
> IDLE
```

Answer (score 0):

> So does that meaning apache_beam spark runner with python can't be implemented on remote spark cluster(yarn mostly)

We've recently added [portable Spark jars](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/10287), which can be submitted via `spark-submit`. This feature isn't scheduled be included a Beam release until 2.19.0, however.

I created a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8970) to track the status of YARN support, in case there are other related issues that need to be addressed.

> and the every ./gradlew command blocked at 98%

That's expected behavior. The job server will stay running until canceled.